# Google Admin Directory API - Send a query via apiclient

Tags: python, google-api, apiclient

I am retrieving a ChromeOS device MAC address via the Google Admin Directory API using the device's Serial Number as reference, and am making my calls through 
`apiclient`.

`service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', developerKey=settings.API_KEY)`

[Here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.chromeosdevices.html) are the calls available for ChromeOS devices; my issue is that I require a Device ID in order to execute the following:

```
service.chromeosdevices().get(customerId=settings.CID, deviceId=obtained_id, projection=None).execute()
```

I can send a GET query via the following format:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/devices/chromeos?projection=full&query=id:" + serial + "&orderBy=status&sortOrder=ascending&maxResults=10", "GET")
```

... but I'm trying to avoid using OAuth2 and just use my API key. Passing the `key` in a `GET` request doesn't work either, as it still returns a **"Login Required"** notice.

How do I squeeze the above query into an `apiclient`-friendly format? The only option I found via the above calls was to request *every* device we have (via `list`), then sift through the mountain of data for the matching Serial number, which seems silly and excessive.

I did notice I could call `apiclient.http.HttpRequests`, but I couldn't find a way to pass the API key through it either. There's `new_batch_http_request`, but I can't discern from the docs how to simply pass a URL to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### Got it!

You can't use just a key for Directory API queries, you need a Service account.

I'm using `google-auth` ([see here](http://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)) since `oauth2client` is deprecated.

You also need to:

- Delegate the necessary permissions for your service account (mine has the role of `Viewer` and has scope access to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos.readonly)
- Delegate API access to it separately in the Admin Console (Security -> Advanced Settings -> Authentication)
- Get your `json` client secret key and place it with your app (don't include it in your VCS)

Obtain your credentials like this:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    settings.CLIENT_KEY,
    scopes=settings.SCOPES,
    subject=settings.ADMIN_USER)
```

where ADMIN_USER is the email address of an authorized Domain admin.

Then you send a GET request like so:

```
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)
response = authed_session.get(request_id_url)
```

This returns a **Requests** object you can read via `response.content`.

Hope it helps someone else!